# Allow users to upload with google forms without login and link it to an outside custom form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Google Form that generates a pdf from a doc template based on the user input, I was able to link the form to a custom html form by changing the form action to point to the form and change the name of the input to point at each Google Form input.

The system works perfectly but when I added an upload input, it doesn't work. And the reason why is that google don't allow upload without login.

I've seen a multiple workaround for this by allowing users to use my login to upload on their behalf but so far none of the workarounds were complete to fit my project.

I created a folder with all the files and folders in it

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P3ipu1rjXnaK-Wu2R3AAvN-et6yX7-U7?usp=sharing

and here is the custom html form code:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfMx2RaoTxiERtqmRCsGD3zEPOQOhQ8h3lf1MFYIAWtNB7cBA/formResponse">
<div>    
    <label>Name</label>    
    <input type="text" name="entry.1492712340">
</div>    
<div>    
    <label>Image</label>    
    <input type="file" name="entry.1275616882">
</div>    
<div>    
    <button type="button" name="">Button</button>    
</div>
</div>
```

Using the above form will redirect the user to google forms which beats the purpose

Again what I'm trying to do is to allow users to use my custom form to submit the form without having to login or redirecting to Google Forms.

I also don't want to use a third party library like *formfacede*

Also I realize that I setup Google Forms to collect Emails, but even with this turned off the custom form doesn't work

Comment: Why are you tied to use a Google Form ?

Comment: I am not but it offered all the features, it can convert to pdf, and store the uploaded images, but if there's a different way, I can use that as well

Comment: In your situation, the email is required to be got?

Comment: There are libraries like formfacade that can override that by using my account to upload the docs, but I was hoping that I can do the same with app script without relying on 3rd party libraries